# How do I stop the page to display a particular warning (see detail), using exception handling or error handling?

Tags: php, error-handling, exception

I'm receiving this particular warning:

> Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\OnlineQuiz\Resultpage.php
>   on line 98

I've used a division expression. Something like this:

```
Ratio = Correct answers/Attempted questions
```

if both things are 0, I'll get the warning. But I don't want this. I just want a message instead of this error. How do handle this?

Comment: So where are we with question

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `$Attempted_questions` to not be zero before division:

```
if ($Attempted_questions != 0) {
  $Ratio = $Correct_answers / $Attempted_questions
}
```

Comment: $Correct_answers/$Attempted_questions

Answer (score 0):

by adding `@` sign before operation to ignore errors:

```
Ratio = @Correct answers/Attempted questions
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

Add `@` sign before operation to ignore errors report/messages

```
Ratio = @Correct_answers / $Attempted_questions
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `try..catch` along with `throw` as

```
function makeratio($Correct_answers, $Attempted_questions) {
    if (!$Attempted_questions) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero');
    }
    return $result = ($Correct_answers / $Attempted_questions);
}

try {
    echo makeratio($Correct_answers, $Attempted_questions);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught Exception : ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```